How do I deal with a parameter that can be a specific type or null
I was just taking an online assessment where I ran into an error stating 'Argument of type 'Date| null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'
This was when I was using this function:
function followingDay(date: Date): Date {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1)
}

I was trying to pass in var3 to the function from an input of this type:
interface User {
  var1: number;
  var2: Date;
  var3: Date | null;
}

When I was doing this I had already placed the function call within an if statement that made sure User.var3!= null
How do I get this error to not come up? I looked around a bunch and couldn't find a solution. This was the only thing I found that looked close but did not work. Overall I was trying to get the millisecond time of that var3 if it was present in the imputed user
var day = (user.var3!= null ? followingDay(user.var3).getTime() : null)


Why do you say that the solution didn't work overall? if the var3 is possible to be null, you need to check if it's not null before using it anywhere as a Date type.

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your problem. Right now this doesn't seem to be reproducible. If I put that into a standalone IDE as shown in this playground link it works. Note that to be a [mre] you can't just say "it doesn't work", you have to say exactly what the problem is and where. Right now the question risks being closed as needing debugging details or not being reproducible.

The code you provided should work just fine. There might be a configuration issue.

Since you are certain it is non-null (from your if check condition I assume you are), you can use the non-null assertion operator to assert this to Typescript:
var day = (user.var3 != null ? followingDay(user.var3!).getTime() : null)
See Non-null assertion operator. [typescriptlang.org]

Here is one way to do it, narrowing the type using a type predicate:
interface User1 {
  var1: number;
  var2: Date;
  var3: Date;


interface User2 {   
  var1: number;   
  var2: Date;   
  var3: null; 
}

type User = User1 | User2

function isUser1(user: User): User is User1 { return !!user.var3 }

if (isUser1(user)) { 
  // user.var3 is type Date here
  console.log(followingDate(user.var3)) 
}

